# How do I pass null to a JSP tag without converting it to default value?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have the following JSP tag:

```
<%@ attribute name="myAttr" required="true" type="java.lang.Boolean" %>
${myAttr}
```

And I have an object with a null field, which I want to pass to the tag as an attribute:

```
<myTags:myTag myAttr="${myObj.nullField}"/>
```

I expect my tag to print out an empty string, but instead, it prints `false`.

Comment: Change the type of your attribute from java.lang.Boolean to java.lang.String maybe?

Comment: yes,like @ryuu9187 mentioned, having attribute type as String should do the job!Plz check and update